# DSE Graph: traversals that use both secondary and search indexes, why do they hang?

Tags: datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup, datastax-enterprise-graph

It seems that gremlin traversals which use both secondary and search indexes in the same traversal hang. Why is that?

My understanding from the DSE Graph [docs on indexing](http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/graph/using/indexingTOC.html) is that the most appropriate index for low-cardinality properties is a secondary index. I have a model with a 'type' property such that there are a limited number of possible types; so when I needed an index I used a secondary index.

But it seems that it's not possible to use both secondary and search indexes in the same traversal, as demonstrated by the following example:

```
gremlin> system.graph('example').create()
==>null
gremlin> :remote config alias g example.g
==>g=example.g
gremlin> schema.vertexLabel('item').create()
==>null
gremlin> schema.propertyKey('type').Text().single().create()
==>null
gremlin> schema.propertyKey('description').Text().single().create()
==>null
gremlin> schema.vertexLabel('item').properties('type').add()
==>null
gremlin> schema.vertexLabel('item').properties('description').add()
==>null
gremlin> schema.vertexLabel('item').index('byType').secondary().by('type').add()
==>null
gremlin> schema.vertexLabel('item').index('search').search().by('description').add()
==>null
gremlin> graph.addVertex(label, 'item', 'type', 'A', 'description', 'first item is orange')
==>v[{~label=item, community_id=96406144, member_id=0}]
gremlin> graph.addVertex(label, 'item', 'type', 'A', 'description', 'second item is blue')
==>v[{~label=item, community_id=2076720128, member_id=0}]
gremlin> graph.addVertex(label, 'item', 'type', 'B', 'description', 'third item is green')
==>v[{~label=item, community_id=51027072, member_id=0}]
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('item').has('type', 'A')
==>v[{~label=item, community_id=2076720128, member_id=0}]
==>v[{~label=item, community_id=96406144, member_id=0}]
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('item').has('description', Search.token('blue'))
==>v[{~label=item, community_id=2076720128, member_id=0}]
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('item').has('type', 'A').has('description', Search.token('blue'))
```

On the last traversal, the server logs the following statement in `/var/log/cassandra/system.log`:

```
WARN  [gremlin-server-worker-1] 2016-09-15 14:26:49,759  GremlinExecutor.java:267 - Timing out script - g.V().hasLabel('item').has('type', 'A').has('description', Search.token('blue')) - in thread [gremlin-server-worker-1]
```

And the console freezes up completely, and doesn't even respond to SIGTERM.

Comment: We are looking into this on our side, I sent an email your way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved by DSE v5.0.3.